# Why does running tests through jenkins user on build slave fail with Missing scala-library.jar?

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, scala-2.11

I'm trying to run a jenkins job, that fails due to: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing scala-library.jar`

When running this line:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -Xmx4250M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /tmp/jenkins/slaves/build-slave-cb996aa/tools/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder_SbtInstallation/default/bin/sbt-launch.jar 'set credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", $ARTIFACTORY_HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD)' assembly`

When running from my own user on the machine or from root, it works fine (fetches the artifacts from jFrog, compiles, runs the tests and packs the jar), but when running from the user `jenkins` it fails.

I found that when running it from root, it finds the library in the path `/root/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.11/scala-library-2.11.11.jar`

I'm running with `sbt.version = 0.13.8` , and `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`
I obviously don't want the jenkins job to work using root, we all know that's not right. 
The full stack is:

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing scala-library.jar
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$file$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:382)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1$$anonfun$file$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:382)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.file$1(Defaults.scala:382)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:384)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$scalaInstanceFromUpdate$1.apply(Defaults.scala:374)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:scalaInstance) Missing scala-library.jar
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago. If I recall the circumstances correctly, my *SBT* build utilized the [`coursier`](https://github.com/coursier/coursier) plugin (resulting in a `~/.coursier`—`%HOME%\.coursier` on *Windows*—directory being created and maintained by the build) and I was also using a local artifact repository (*Nexus OSS*, in my case).

My problem turned out to be the version of the `coursier` plugin that my build was using. If you're using `coursier` *v1.0.0-RC2* (or possibly *v1.0.0-RC3*) or earlier, then this might explain your problem.

The solution was to delete the `.coursier` and `.ivy2` directories (which cache some artifacts locally), change the version of `coursier` to *V1.0.0-RC4* or later, and re-try the build. (In your case, these directories would be on your *Jenkins* server, in the `jenkins` account home.)

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the cache in the server and also moved the coursier from the project/plugins.sbt file : ```addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.0")``` to the build.sbt file : ```libraryDependencies +="io.get-coursier" %% "coursier" % "1.0.1"```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the library path with root user is pointing to **.cache**.did you try by clearing the cache.

And also can you try by executing the below command got from

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true)